# How to catch a signal multiple times in BonitaSoft?

Tags: business-process-management, bonita

I'm calling from **`Signal5`** to **`Signal2`** until the number of calls is 10 (XOR Gateway).

But the problem is that **`Signal3`** call **`Signal4`** two times and **the process is lost**.

I think that the first pool is waiting for some action or the signals can be called only once.

[image: Bonita Process]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no action running in parallel maybe a design with a call activity (Step 3 on my diagram below) might answer what you want to achieve:
[image: process model with call activity]